# Have trivial properties ever saved your bacon?

Tags: c#, .net

There's a lot of advice out there that you shouldn't expose your fields publically, and instead use trivial properties.  I see it over & over.

I understand the arguments, but [I don't think it's good advice in most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174198/c35-automatic-properties-why-not-access-the-field-directly#205567).

Does anyone have an example of a time when it really mattered?  When writing a trivial property made something important possible in the future (or when failing to use one got them in to real trouble)?

EDIT: The DataBinding argument is correct, but not very interesting.  It's a bug in the DataBinding code that it won't accept public fields.  So, we have to write properties to work around that bug, not because properties are a wise class design choice.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm looking for real-world examples, not theory.  A time when it really mattered.

EDIT: The ability to set a breakpoint on the setter seems valuable.  Designing my code for the debugger is unfortunate: I'd rather the debugger get smarter, but given the debugger we have, I'll take this ability.  Good stuff.

Comment: in your comment to @JasonBunting you lament about immutable types and readonly. I'm curious why you can't achieve this with 
MyProperty { get; private set; }?

Comment: @Robert: Because I don't get for-free verification that my implementation isn't modifying state.

Comment: If you don't trust yourself, use a backing field and write unit tests.
private readonly string name; 
public string Name { get { return name; } }
'property or indexer '...Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @Paulson: that's hellishly more complex and *still* less reliable than simply using the obvious language feature `readonly`.  You're suggesting to not just write extra code at the member sight, but unit tests for a behaviorless part of your problem.   That quite some code bloat (really bad for readability and maintainability) for a simple field - of which you may have thousands in a program.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It may be hard to make code work in an uncertain future, but that's no excuse to be lazy. Coding a property over a field is convention and it's pragmatic. Call it defensive programming.

Other people will also complain that there's a speed issue, but the JIT'er is smart enough to make it just about as fast as exposing a public field. Fast enough that I'll never notice.

Some non-trivial things that come to mind

1. A public field is totally public, you can not impose read-only or write-only semantics
2. A property can have have different `get` versus `set` accessibility (e.g. public get, internal set)
3. You can not override a field, but you can have virtual properties.
4. Your class has no control over the public field
5. Your class can control the property. It can limit setting to allowable range of values, flag that the state was changed, and even lazy-load the value.
6. Reflection semantics differ. A public field is not a property.
7. No databinding, as others point out. (It's only a bug to you. - I can understand Why .net framework designers do not support patterns they are not in favour of.)
8. You can not put a field on an interface, but you can put a property on an interface.
9. Your property doesn't even need to store data. You can create a facade and dispatch to a contained object.

You only type an extra 13 characters for correctness. That hardly seems like speculative generality. There is a semantic difference, and if nothing else, a property has a different semantic meaning and is far more flexible than a public field.

```
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string name;
```

I do recall one time when first using .net I coded a few classes as just fields, and then I needed to have them as properties for some reason, and it was a complete waste of time when I could have just done it right the first time.

So what reasons do you have for *not* following convention? Why do you feel the need to swim upstream? What has it saved you by not doing this?

Comment: This is a great response! Most comprehensive I have found anywhere while researching the topic.

Comment: Loved this line: "So what reasons do you have for not following convention? Why do you feel the need to swim upstream? What has it saved you by not doing this?"  I've been asking a co-worker the exact same thing since he insists on formatting his C# as if it is mainframe ANSI C from 1972.

Comment: What you win is clarity: guarranteed no behavior, some speed (the JIT is not magic), the ability to mark the field readonly, more useful code-coverage metrics.  I find the clarity and simplicity argument extremely compelling unless  there's reason to think you need one of the features 1-9 you mention, I'd follow YAGNI.  Keep it simple!

Comment: e.g 1.: you *can* impose readonly semantics; even readonly semantics in a more robust fashion whereby *no* code can update the field post-constructor.  2.: if you need this, you know it and should use a property - no reason to use one if you don't, however. 3. again, rare, but if you need it: sure. 4. Neither does it over automatic properties. 5. It can't for autoproperties.  6. this cuts both ways; just fix the reflection code... 7. If you need it, *then* use a property. etc.

Comment: @Eamon - Why don't you make your own answer. The long-ago-answered question was about non-trivial concerns and differences between the two. (I don't mention speed because it's ridiculous in this context.) 
Its important to note that you can convert an auto property to a field-backed property _without_ affecting binary compatibility or reflection semantics, etc. Properties are more flexable, and I can create an immutable class easily without resorting to readonly public fields either. Properties are not a heavyweight construction, and public fields are a hangover of old code.

Comment: If you don't need the extra runtime flexibility; it's at best inconvenient and at worst dangerous.  I added this as a comment because I don't believe that public fields are a holdover of old code: I think they're the superior solution excepting the very valid but nevertheless less common corner cases you actually need properties for; and further that I see people using them all over the place in internal (though not private) code because of this misleading recommendation.  More runtime flexiblity is not intrinsically better - as the choice to use a statically typed language shows.

Comment: @Eamon enough with the platitudes please. I don't recall saying "never use fields", and no code is 'dangerous'. We get you don't like properties, but please don't proselytize (in a comment).

Most of your comments were "well if you need that you'll know to use use properties". But that's the entire point - to illustrate all the ways, possibly to those that do not (yet) know, that choosing a property and not a public field is probably a safe bet, and is far more robust than choosing a public field.

Comment: PS Using reflection, one is able to modify a readonly field, so using it for immutability is only slightly more robust. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-using-reflection

Comment: @Paulson: I understand you don't appreciate the criticism of your answer; I don't appreciate the defensive attitude.  I think your points 6. and 7. are meaningful, and binary compatibility requirements make others meaningful - I just think that as a general list, you've overstated the case.  In the choice between fields and auto-properties, it's (IMHO) a good idea for a programmer to consider the specific scenario and realize the guideline has plenty of exceptions.

Comment: @Eamon please stop. I supplied an answer to the 'public fields versus public property'. I've said why I feel it's a pragmatic choice with 9 non-trivial reasons. By all means, disagree. Create your own answer as to why public properties are a superior solution, and how they saved your bacon. Link that to the comments and lets delete this useless exchange. If people feel you have a good answer, they will upvote it, and it will be much easier to follow.

Answer (score 13):

I used to think the same thing, Jay.  Why use a property if it's only there to provide *direct* access to a private member?  If you can describe it as an autoproperty, having a property at all rather than a field seemed kind of silly.  Even if you ever need to change the implementation, you could always just refactor into a real property later and any dependent code would still work, right?.  Well, maybe not.

You see, I've recently seen the light on trivial properties, so maybe now I can help you do the same.

What finally convinced me was the fairly obvious point (in retrospect) that properties in .Net are just syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods, and those methods have a *different name* from the property itself.  Code in the same assembly will still work, because you have to recompile it at the same time anyway.  But any code in a different assembly that links to yours will *fail* if you refactor a field to a property, unless it's recompiled against your new version at the same time.  If it's a property from the get-go, everything is still good.

Comment: Can you rebuild the other assemblies?  If yes, then you don't have a problem.  If no, your porblem is much bigger.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174198/c35-automatic-properties-why-not-access-the-field-directly#205567

Comment: If your code is a commercial class library and you make the change from public field to property, you could REALLY irritate your customers.

Comment: @BlackWasp: That's the theory, but have you ever actually needed to do that?  And not needed to make other breaking changes?  When binary compatibility was a requirement?

Comment: @BlackWasp: and what you're saying is describing a vanishingly small portion of all properties.  Most will not be assembly public; those that are will often be interface implementations (no choice there), or they will be non-trivial; or they will be intrinsically trivial (no way you'll change em to be trivial), or your clients can and will recompile and are unlikely to be bitten.  In this extremely rare scenario where you have a coincidentally trivial propery in a major independantly distributed libarary - sure, use a property.

Answer (score 13):

I've had a trivial property save me a couple of times when debugging.  .Net doesn't support the concept of a data break point (read or write).  Occasionally when debugging a very complex scenario it was important to track read/writes to a particular property.  This is easy with a property but impossible with a field.

If you're not working in a production environment, it's simple to refactor a field -> property for the purpose of debugging.  Occasionally though you hit bugs that only reproduce in a production environment that is difficult to patch with a new binary.  A property can save you here.

It's a fairly constrained scenario though.

Comment: I was just posting a similar point. I'll get you next time, Gadget.

Comment: I sometimes use this ability.  But it's not a real argument for using properties rather than fields in advance; after all, you can change the field temporarily for that debug run very easily - something you'll need to do for private non-property members anyhow if you wish to exploit this technique.

Answer (score 11):

I'll answer your question with another one: have you ever really benefited from not making all your types and members public? I suspect I haven't directly prevented any bugs by doing so. However, I've encapsulated my types properly, only exposing what's meant to be exposed. Properties are similar - good design more than anything else. I think of properties as conceptually different from fields; they're part of the contract rather than being fundamentally part of the implementation. Thinking about them as properties rather than fields helps me to think more clearly about my design, leading to better code.

Oh, and I've benefited occasionally from not breaking source compatibility, being able to set breakpoints, log access etc.

Comment: Good response.  I think I have benefitted from coding the way I do, but there's definitely room to challenge that way, and for me to improve.  Unfortunately I think it's too complex to figure out in a Stack Overflow comment thread!

Comment: Further discourse by Jon:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Part of the idea is that those properties may not be trivial in the future - if you bound external code to a field and later wanted to wrap that in a property, all of the dependent code would have to change, and you may not be able to do that, especially in the case where you are a control designer or have libraries that you can't control, etc.

Not to mention there are certain .NET practices that will not allow you to use a field - databinding particularly.

I am sure there are other good reasons as well. Why does it matter to you? Use an automatic property and be done with it. Seems like something not worth being concerned about to me...

Comment: Databinding is broken.  Sucks.  Guess I have to deal with taht.

Automatic properties don't allow 'readonly', making immutable types a little harder.

I'd like my properties to stand as saying "Watch out! This isn't just data!"

Comment: You can do an automatic property with a private set, which gets you part of the way there.

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier to debug a problem involving a field if it is wrapped by a property accessor. Placing breakpoints in the accessor can quite quickly help with finding re-entrancy and other issues that otherwise might not be caught. By marshaling all access to the field through an accessor, you can ascertain exactly who is changing what and when.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, from my understanding, you cannot databind to public fields; but only to properties.  Thus, if you want to do databinding, you have no choice.

Comment: Yes, DataBinding has that bug.

Comment: For databinding, you typically also want update notification (INotifyPropertyChanged) so a property is therefore needed to raise the event.

Comment: If you want update notification, it's not a trivial property and get;set; won't work anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I once had fields that I wanted to expose from a windows from project which allowed the stats for the program (TotalItems and SuccessfulItems).

Later I decided to display the stats on the form and was able to add a call in the setter that updated the display when the property changed.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if you're not creating a shared class library, and you're not using DataBinding, then using a field will cause you no problems whatsoever.

But if you're creating a shared class library, you'd be foolish IMHO to do otherwise than follow the guidelines, for the usual three reasons:

- consumers of your shared class library may want to use DataBinding.
- consumers of your shared class might want binary compatibility, which is not possible if you switch from a field to a property.
- the principal of least surprise implies you should be consistent with other shared class libraries including the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: RE: binary compatibility: I think people don't need it as much as they say, and that tirival properties aren't enough.  See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174198/c35-automatic-properties-why-not-access-the-field-directly#205567

Comment: It's not just binary compatibility - it's source compatibility too.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no such thing as a trivial property as people have been calling them. Via the way things such as databinding work, Microsoft has implied that any bit of data that is a part of the public interface of an object should be a property. I don't think they meant it merely to be a convention like it is in some other languages where property syntax is more about convention and convenience.

A more interesting question may be: "When should I use a public field instead of a property", or "When has a public field instead of a public property saved your bacon?"

Comment: I think that Microsoft made a mistake in the Reflection APIs, making it easy to reflect over properties alone, but not over properties+fields together.  That mistake has influenced the design of many other systems, and now we're stuck with it.

Comment: Jay, I totally understand what you are saying. I've programmed in other languages so I can see your point from a language agnostic point of view. However, this language works the way Microsoft designed it to work, not what makes sense to you or I.

Answer (score 0):

Fields which are of structure types allow direct access to the members thereof, while properties of such types do not.  Consequently, if `Thing.Boz` were a field of type `Point`, code which wants to modify its `X` value could simply say `Thing.Boz.X += 5;`; if `Thing.Boz` were a mutable property, it would be necessary to use `var tmp = Thing.Boz; tmp.X += 5; Thing.Boz = tmp;`.  The ability to write things more cleanly with the exposed field is often, *but not always*, a blessing.

If it will always be possible for `Boz` to be a field, modifying its members directly will be cleaner, faster, and better than copying it to a temporary variable, modifying that, and copying it back.  If the type of `Boz` exposes its mutable fields directly (as structures should) rather than wrapping them in trivial wrappers, it will also be possible to use things like `Interlocked` methods on them--something that's simply impossible with properties.  There's really only one disadvantage to using fields in that way: if it's ever necessary to replace the field with a property, code which relied upon the thing being a field will break, and may be hard to fix.

In short, I would posit that in cases where one isn't concerned about being able to swap in different versions of code without having to recompile any consumers, the biggest effect of using properties rather than fields is to prevent consumers of the code from writing code which would take advantage of (and rely upon) the semantics of exposed fields which are of structure types.

Incidentally, an alternative to exposing a field of a structure type would be to expose an `ActOnXXX` method.  For example:

```
delegate void ActionByRef<T1>(ref T1 p1);
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2,T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2, ref T3 p3);
// Method within the type that defines property `Boz`
void ActOnBoz<T1>(ActionByRef<Point, T1> proc, ref T1 p1)
{
  proc(ref _Boz, ref p1); // _Boz is the private backing field
}
```

Code which wanted to add some local variable `q` to `Thing.Boz.X` could call `Thing.ActOnBoz((ref Point pt, ref int x) => {pt.X += x;}, ref q);` and have the action performed directly on `Thing._Boz`, even though the field is not exposed.