# How does DataContractSerializer write to private fields?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

I understand how XMLSerializer could work by using reflection to figure out what public read/write fields or properties it should be using to serialize or de-serialize XML. Yet XMLSerializer requires that the fields be public and read/write.

However, DataContractSerializer is able to read or write to or from completely private fields in a class. So I'm wondering how this is even possible with out explicitly giving DataContractSerializer additional access rights to my class(es).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reflection has many features. `XmlSerializer` has, via "sgen.exe" the ability to pre-build the serialization code to a binary (dll). This is useful in some scenarios that don't allow dynamic code, but dlls (just like your code) are limited to the accessible API.

However... reflection *isn't* this limited, and with enough access you can do pretty much anything. For performance you probably don't want to be using reflection *directly* a lot, but if you have enough permissions to create IL directly in memory (`DynamicMethod`), then you can tell it (on a per-dynamic-method basis) which `Type` the code is associated with. For example, if I create a `DynamicMethod` passing `typeof(Foo)` as the `owner` argument, then that dynamic method has full access to all members (including fields) on `Foo`. For info, `Delegate.CreateDelegate` provides similar access to otherwise protected data. Since `DataContractSerializer` doesn't worry about pre-generation, it can use this access.

Answer (score 2):

It does it the same way the `XMLSerializer` does, by using reflection.

The difference is that `XMLSerializer` will not touch private fields but the `DataContractSerializer` will.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-using-reflection) SO question and answers about reflection and changing of private fields.