# Protect value from changes using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

here is the problem case i am writing a little third party library. In this library i have a class like this

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public int TestField { get; private set; }

        public TestClass( )
        {
            TestField = 1;
        }
    }
```

Then i have a varialbe form this class like this

```
 public TestClass test = new TestClass( );
```

The problem i am facing is that usnig reflection like this

```
PropertyInfo field = typeof( TestClass ).GetProperty( "TestField" );
            field.SetValue( test, 2, null );
```

programers can change internal value of this class. this will be very bad thing becouse it can crash the hole library. My question is what is the best way to protect my code form such changes.I know i can use some kind of bool flag so tha value can be changed only ones but this is not very good salution is there a better one?
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about it. If someone goes to that much trouble to change a property then I think they are responsible for the consequences. You've marked the setter private. That is all you should do. What situations do you think would arise where a programmer would even try to do this to your library? I think you're leaning toward over design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please understand that I mean this with all respect:

You are wasting your time. Seriously.

Reflection is not to be considered when specifying an API or contract.

Believe this. It is not possible to stop reflection. If a consumer is bent on peeking into your code and flipping bits that have been hidden for a reason, well, the consequences are on them, not you.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to protect your system from something that is *stronger* than your code. If you don't trust certain code, run it with partial trust - then when it asks to reflect your type it will be denied.

Reflection (and related techniques like `DynamicMethod`) can **with enough trust** get virtually unrestricted access to your data (even, for example, changing the *characters* of a `string` without ever re-assigning it); thus you must reduce trust for non-trusted code.

In a similar way, anyone with debugger or admin access to your process (or the dlls it loads) can subvert your code. This is not an interesting attack, as the "hacker" must *already* have *at least* as much access than your code (probably more).

Comment: The attack is interesting in the case of an anti-theft or anti-tampering package.  You can't really protect against somebody crashing your app if they have full control over your app, but you can make it much more difficult to modify certain key state that enforces your protection scheme.  I don't think this is what the OP is doing, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can even [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-using-reflection/934942#934942) the `private readonly` field using reflection. So, your best bet may the `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReadOnly` value, if you want a constant value. or just use `const`.

Use `Enum`, in case that you have a few 'safe values' that you want to customer (programmer) to choose one of them.

Edit: Apparently, `enum` not safe enough. you can use `readonly` field with the following format:

```
public class SafeValue
{
    private string _value;

    public static readonly SafeValue Value1 = new SafeValue("value1");
    public static readonly SafeValue Value2 = new SafeValue("value2");

    private SafeValue(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: readonly would work, assuming the value never needs to change once set in the constructor, but how does Enum help? Someone can still change the value through reflection.

Comment: @Mendy - enums are not validated; I can change your enum value to -142526 and the system won't care.

Comment: @Marc interesting. care to say how?

Comment: @Mendy - you can cast any int value. The compiler doesn't check. so 'SomeEnum value = -142526;' Won't compile but `SomeEnum value = (SomeEnum) -142526;` will. Even if -142526 isn't a valid value in `SomeEnum`.

Comment: @Marc now I'm totally confused. the `readonly` directive compiled into MSIL, but not honored?

Comment: readonly can't force the field to never change via Reflection (or direct memory tweaking), but it could create all sorts of interesting side effects due to compiler optimizations assuming the field never changes.

Comment: @Mendy - yup; this is required for remoting and some (not all) forms  of serialization