# Access a private variable

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm modding a game, and I've run across a problem. I'm trying to draw text to the screen in C# with .NET and XNA, so i'm using XNA's SpriteBatch.

The problem is, I can't modify any source files. I can only load external *.cs* files. I can LOOK at the source, and the variable is defined as so in the class `Main.cs`:

```
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
```

If I define my own SpriteBatch as so:

```
public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
```

then it doesn't draw, because I don't have a draw method. Now, all I want to do is access `Main.spriteBatch`, but that variable is private as mentioned before.

Any ideas?

Comment: What class has the `spriteBatch` field.  Main.cs is a file not a class

Comment: I think you may be approaching this the wrong way.  If the class author hid the variable, then you shouldn't edit it.  I recommend trying to find another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I general, breaking encapsulation is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to retrieve the value of private variables or methods.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public Calculator() { ... }
        private double _number;
        public double Number { get { ... } set { ... } }
        public void Clear() { ... }
        private void DoClear() { ... }
        public double Add(double number) { ... }
        public static double Pi { ... }
        public static double GetPi() { ... }
    }
}

Calculator calc = new Calculator();

// invoke private instance method: private void DoClear()
calcType.InvokeMember("DoClear",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null, calc, null);
```

To invoke with arguments, pass a array of the arguments in instead of null.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) to further documentation from the msdn.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for. spriteBatch isn't a variable, it's a sub-function. I'm trying to call Main.spriteBatch.DrawString.

Comment: Either way you can do it using reflection: `calcType.InvokeMember("Clear",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
    null, calcInstance, null);
`

Comment: With reflection you can also call a private Method!http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect.getmethod.aspx

Comment: It might be worth noting that reflection will probably only work on Windows games. Xbox and Windows Phone 7 runtime environments have restrictions around such things.

Comment: @lzcd: XNA allows reflection (PC and xbox, don't know about phone). It's slow though, so do it once to get a reference to the `spritebatch` on loading.

Comment: So something like this: `SpriteBatch spriteBatch = MethodInfo GetMethod(string spriteBatch, BindingFlags (BindingAttr) Default);`
EDIT: it throws an "Invalid token: Using" where I put `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: If you have access to the class type without using reflections then there is no need to use `GetMethod`; simply use `InvokeMember` directly.  Otherwise you will need to use `GetType` as well.

Comment: If you're having a new problem it would be easier if you created a new question so you can post code.

Comment: @mydogisbox no, i'm just not quite sure how to do this. I'm  a beginner to C#. What code would I use to do this? All I want is to call Main.spriteBatch.DrawString();

Comment: I don't know why you're having problems with your using statement, but other than that I have posted pretty much everything you need to invoke the method.  Simply replace your object and method name in the example I gave.  If you have issues with getting your using statement to work that would probably require asking a new question.

Comment: @mydogisbox Ah, I didn't see your edit. If the function I'm calling takes arguments, where would I input them? The MSDN doc isn't really help.

Comment: Updated with more information and a useful link to the msdn (does contain notes on how to pass in arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to access the private member, but this isn't a recommended practice to actually use. The internal implementation of objects is subject to change and accessing them is a violation of good OOP principal.

The similar answer here will help you accomplish the task though:

[Can I change a private readonly field in C# using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection)