# Is it possible to externally modify private variables of a class instance?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, memory, structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change a private readonly field in C# using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection)

I need to modify a data structure class, but the data is hidden behind a read-only property. Can I, using any technique, modify private variables within a class?

What if I was able to peer into the object and note down exact byte positions of the variables I need. Can I then use unsafe code to directly modify memory at those offsets? Is anything like this possible?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use Reflection tecniques to modify the variables of the instance. It is not dificult:

```
typeof(MyClassType).GetField("TheField",BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(ClassInstance,NewValue);
```

Remember to include the system.reflection namespace.

Comment: yes you can doesn't mean that you should :)

Comment: Reflection must be used with caution, but it's a powerfull tool and can save you a lot of time/code sometimes. :D