# Why can't I change Type.Delimiter using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

If I were to change the value of `bool.TrueString`, I'd do it using Reflection:

```
typeof(bool).GetField("TrueString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, "Yes");
Console.WriteLine(bool.TrueString); // Outputs "Yes"
```

However, I cannot manage to change the value of, say, `Type.Delimiter`:

```
typeof(Type).GetField("Delimiter", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, '-');
Console.WriteLine(Type.Delimiter); // Outputs "."
```

Why is this?

Comment: Not sure, seems like a horrible idea anyway.

Comment: looking at the source the two fields are declared almost the same but not quite, one is read-only = ".", the other is read only = another read-only literal.

Comment: A wild guess. Since bool is a `struct` and `Type` is an abstract class, Reflection might perform some black magic on that struct. As i said.. just a guess

Comment: The question should be called "Why can't I change a static readonly field using Reflection". This has nothing to do with specific classes.

Comment: @usr But I am changing `bool.TrueString`, so that's not entirely true

Comment: It would behave the same for any other class and it would clarify the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're falling prey to an optimization that's being performed by the JIT.  You actually can change the value of that field but, for some reason, the results of that change won't be immediately visible.  I managed to get around that by doing something stupid:

```
typeof(Type).GetField("Delimiter", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, '-');
Func<char> getDelimiter = () => Type.Delimiter;
Console.WriteLine( getDelimiter() );
```

This code reliably showed the updated value of the field for me.  I can't say I'm terribly surprised; the field is declared as read-only, so the JITter may use that assumption when accessing the field.  You're doing something naughty and evil, there shouldn't really be any expectation for this to work in a sane way.

Now, as for why this didn't show up when modifying the `bool.TrueString` field, my best guess is that it's due to `bool.TrueString` being a reference type (`string`) whereas `Type.Delimiter` is a value type (`char`).  I could imagine this triggering different optimizations.

I did look at the disassembly for this code:

```
        Console.WriteLine( bool.TrueString );
006F2E53 8B 0D B8 10 40 03    mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[34010B8h]  
006F2E59 E8 52 A6 77 54       call        54E6D4B0  

        Console.WriteLine(Type.Delimiter);
006F2E5E B9 2E 00 00 00       mov         ecx,2Eh  
006F2E63 E8 B0 FA E0 54       call        55502918
```

You can see pretty clearly that the JITter optimized away the `Type.Delimiter` field access by replacing it with the literal value `'.'`.  The static field access for `bool.TrueString` still appear to load from the actual field.

Comment: It's because jitting this code executes the static ctor, then burns Delimiter into the x86 code. The delegate version does not reference Delimiter from this method. Delimiter is still burned into the x86 code but for a different method at a later time.

Comment: @usr I actually noticed the field changing by testing the code in LINQPad, which prompted me to try creating a delegate to try and force the jit to see the field value after it was changed.  Honestly it was a bit of a shot in the dark on my part, but it worked out I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `bool.TrueString` is a reference type and `Type.Delimiter` is a value type. Try the same code against these two properties, and you'll see the same behavior:

```
public class A
{
    public static readonly string S = "S";
    public static readonly char C = 'C';
}
```

The reason this happens is that the first time your method is called, the JIT compiler figures whether the `static readonly` value can be baked straight into the assembly code as a constant. If it can, it does.

If you extract out the code that accesses the field to a different method, then its output will depend on whether its first run was *before* or *after* the field's value was changed. Since your code is all in the same method, then it was clearly JITted before the field's value is changed.

You'll find that if you use a value type that can be hard-coded into CPU-facing instructions, this JIT optimization will be applied. This includes things like `int`, `long`, and `char`, but not things like `DateTime`s or reference types like strings