# Set a field readonly with a plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been looking through the net but can't find a proper answer...

I wrote a plugin in C# and when a condition is met, I would like to set a field readonly...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Take a look at the two links one deals with Bindings and the other is an example of how you can do this... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx |http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection

Comment: Read only at the server level, or read only at the client level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that you cant modify a field's enabled/disabled from the plugin.

You can, however, access the fields from javascript:

`Xrm.Page.getControl('yourfieldname').setDisabled(true);`

Here is info on how to setup the javascript for your forms: [microsoft's form programming reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the javascript code, but have you checked out the `AttributeMetadata.IsValidForFilter` property? I can only imagine this can be accessed via a plugin. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.isvalidforupdate.aspx

Comment: +1 Peter, this is a good point, I've never knew that's applicable before.

Comment: @PeterMajeed I didn't consider those properties, good idea. If the OP wants to commit changes to the entity itself that makes sense, if she wants a temporary change on the form she's stuck with javascript.

Comment: Thank you guys ! I was a bit reluctant to use javascript but it did the job very well !