# How to set GridItem Value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am aware this property is read only. But I really need to set the value. Is there a way to change the value of `GridItem (System.Windows.Forms.GridItem)` by using Reflection? If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using reflection.  [Here is a previous post with the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection)

But you most definitely do not want to change it.  It has been designed in such a way for a very important reason.  You will degrade the integrity of the object instance.

Comment: Type valueProperty = typeof(GridItem);

FieldInfo valueField = valueProperty.GetField("value", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

I tried both "Value" and "value", but this always returns null. This is the reason I am asking the question here.