# Initialize array object inside a different class C#

Tags: c#

I would like to understand how to initialize array object from an outside class. Please refer to the code below:

```
Class C
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    private string value { get; set; }
}

Class B
{
    private C[] field;
    public C[] Field { get; set; };
}

Class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        /* my question was how to initialize this array object inside B class */
        b.Field = new C[1]; 
        b.Field[0] = new C(); 
        /* Now I can access b.Field[0].name */ 
    }
}
```

Note that I cannot change Classes B and C as they are already provided to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there no constructor of `C` you can use?

Comment: If you can't change the public interface for `C` perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify class C or class B. :(

Comment: You should be wary of abusing reflection for purposes like this, but sometimes it may be a necessary evil.

Comment: You can't set the name and value of C because they are private (short of reflection) - the array is irrelevant.

Comment: Does the C class have a constructor? Some mutating methods? Because otherwise, I don't see any point in it's existence.

Comment: Please note the Public C[] Field inside Class B. Thanks for all your help, finally got the solution.

Comment: public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        b.Field = new C[1]; b.Field[0] = new C(); //Now I can access b.Field[0].name
    }

Comment: Please don't write "solved" in your question. Instead write an answer to share how you solved it.

Comment: I did, please refer to the comment above. Let me also add it to the code snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can not modify name and value properties from outside of C because they are private.
After making your name and value properties public, you can instantiate your array as follows.

```
B b = new B();
b.Field = new C[] {new C {name = "lorem", value = "ipsum"}, new C {name = "dolor", value = "sit"}};
```

If you use Reflection, create your C objects through a factory as follows.

```
public class CFactory
{
    public C Create(string name, string value)
    {
        C result = new C();
        var props = result.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public
                                                | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

        var nameProp = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "name");
        var valProp = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "value");

        if (nameProp != null) nameProp.SetValue(result, name);
        if (valProp != null) valProp.SetValue(result, value);

        return result;
    }
}
```

and use it;

```
B b = new B();
var fac = new CFactory();
b.Field = new C[] {fac.Create("lorem", "ipsum"), fac.Create("dolor", "sit")};
```