# Setting a property {get;} using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, backing-field

I have a class from a third-party library with a read-only property called `Name`. Here is the code for the class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;}
}
```

I want to set the value of the `Name` property using reflection or another suitable method, but I don't know how the property is implemented. Specifically, I don't know if it has a backing field like this:

```
private string m_name;
```

or if it is implemented like this:

```
public string Name {get; private set;}
```

How can I set the value of the `Name` property in this situation?

Comment: @maccettura https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection

Comment: Huh, today I learned...

Comment: @maccettura me too! Actually!

Comment: @itsme86 This is different. I do not know the backing field here!

Comment: Regarding your actual question, I think this will be impossible until you know the backing field name.  You could try to decompile the dll using DotNetPeek or something?

Comment: @itsme86, this is not a duplicate of that question.  OP _does not_ know the name of the private variable.

Comment: @maccettura Thanks. Yes you are right. I think that is the only way.

Comment: Doesn't it have a `SetName()` method or something like this? Try using the dot navigator

Comment: @Vahid...if its an auto-implemented property then the instance variable for Name would be name.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani With the current builds of Roslyn, the backing field name is `<Name>k__BackingField`.

Comment: `Mono.Reflection` has an extension method `GetBackingField()` for `PropertyInfo` which returns `FieldInfo`. This only works for auto-properties. Since you said it's a 3rd-party library, there's a good chance it's not an auto-property and you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try tomorrow at work! ,)

Comment: There's also the possibility that it does not _have_ a backing field - that the name is generated in the getter somehow.  You _could_ decompile the DLL and look at the getter's code, but I do not know of at automated way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to obtain a `FieldInfo` instance for the property's backing field and call the `SetValue()` method.

The `Mono.Reflection` library (available in Package Manager) will help you find the backing field.

If the Property is an auto-property, you can call the `GetBackingField()` extension method on the `PropertyInfo` instance.

Otherwise, you'll have to disassemble the IL of the `MethodInfo` of the getter like this:

```
var instructions = yourProp.GetGetMethod().GetInstructions();
```

This will give you a list of the method's IL instructions. If they look like this:

```
Ldarg0
Ldfld    (Backing Field)
Ret
```

Then the 2nd Instruction will give you the backing field. In code:

```
if (instructions.Count == 3 && instructions[0].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldarg_0 && instructions[1].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldfld && instructions[2].OpCode == OpCodes.Ret)
{
    FieldInfo backingField = (FieldInfo)instructions[1].Operand;
}
```

Otherwise, the property is probably computed and has no backing field.