# Main differences between Property's and Variables in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use simple properties instead of fields in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c)

If I have a class, does it matter if I use a Variable instead of a Property?  I mean, unless I need something to run during the `get/set` time period, does it really matter?  It still gets the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily "matter" which you do. The reason for using property get/set would be to validate values before they're assigned to the variable and ensure that it can't be directly accessed from outside the class.

If you only have a small application and your class won't be designed to be reusable, I don't see a problem with just using public variables.