# Can some one please explain how the two classes differ in execution?

Tags: c#

I was testing a class in Linqpad and constructed a basic class but cannot get my head around how the two classes differ in execution. Can someone please help me out?

```
public class name // 1
{
    public string name1 {get;set;}
    public surname surname = new surname();
}

public class name // 2
{
    public string name1 {get;set;}
    public surname surname {get;set;}
    public name()
    {
    surname = new surname();
    }
}
public class surname
{
    public string surname1 {get;set;}
    public string surname2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: ... I'm pretty sure the line `public surname = new surname();` is not even valid syntax in C#.

Comment: Nevermind, you edited it.

Comment: it was a fatfinger i edited it.

Comment: Ah, ok. No problem :)

Comment: As a reference, you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i rewrite your classes, clr define your code like this

```
public class name // 1
{
    private string _name1;
    public string get_name1()
    {
         return _name1;
    } 
    public void set_name1(string value)
    {
         this._name1=value;
    } 
    public surname surname = new surname();
}

public class name // 2
{        
    private string _name1;
    public string get_name1()
    {
         return _name1;
    } 
    public void set_name1(string value)
    {
         this._name1=value;
    } 
    private surname _surname = new surname();
    public surname get_surname()
    {
         return _surname;
    } 
    public void set_surname(surname value)
    {
         this._surname=value;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The former compiles to the same as:

```
public class name
{
    public string name1 {get;set;}
    public surname surname;
    public name()
    {
        surname = new surname();
    }
}
```

So the only difference is that in `1` you have a field, and in `2` you have a property. Since it is public, you should use a property. See [Why use simple properties instead of fields in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c) for reasons why.

As an aside, a C# naming convention is that all properties, classes, and methods are PascalCase, not camelCase, so all of the things in your examples (with possible exception of the `surname` field) should begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

One is a field. The other is a property. The surname property in name2 is translated by the compiler into getter and setter method pairs.