# Can I use AutoMapper to map between two fields which are immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have the following two classes (many properties elided for brevity).

Service Layer POCO:

```
public class TicketFlag
{
    public ContactKey ContactKey;
}
```

LINQ to SQL generated POCO:

```
public class TicketFlag
{
    public string ContactKey;    
}
```

When trying to use AutoMapper to map between these two on service calls -> database save, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Type 'ContactKey' does not have a default constructor
```

ContactKey does not have a default constructor on purpose. Basically, it takes a string and a list of objects and can serialize/deserialize itself.

I have tried creating a mapping function (and it's inverse) like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, ContactKey>().ConvertUsing(s => ContactKeySerializer.Serialize(s));
```

But I'm still getting complaints because ContactKey doesn't have a default constructor.

Is there a way to get AutoMapper to not use the default constructor to do it's property mapping? Really, just mapping properties on the ContactKey isn't sufficient - I need to have it call the constructor, or get spit out from my ContactKeySerializer class.

Comment: Are you sure its not because they're `fields` and not `properties`?

Comment: They are fields, thanks for pointing that out. Editing now to clarify. Unsure of why that matters, though. Maybe I need to RTFM :)?

Comment: Can you show the Mapper.Map call, specially the one where you think your CreateMap is used?

Comment: It works for me as-is. Did you eliminate something from your sample code that caused the problem?

Comment: @Tim S There's some helper classes that cache the mapping that I did remove. It could be something there. I'll check. Also going to try your answer (with the ResolveUsing) - not used that one before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should probably be [using properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c) for these things, not fields. However, I doubt that's part of your problem.

Instead of trying to create a map from `string` to `ContactKey`, you could try to make this part of the map from one `TicketFlag` to the other:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<LINQtoSQL.TicketFlag, Service.Layer.TicketFlag>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactKey,
 mem => mem.ResolveUsing(src => ContactKeySerializer.Serialize(src.ContactKey)));
```

I think that would prevent the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper is complaining that you don't have a default constructor because AutoMapper needs to create an empty instance of the target class before it can map values to it. It can't call your ContractKey's parameterized constructor - how would it?

In this case it might seem simple, if the constructor looks like this:

```
public ContracktKey(string keyValue){}
```

But what if it had two parameters?

```
public ContracktKey(string keyValue, string otherValue){}
```

How would it know where to put the value? What if you only provided one string?

I think it would be best to follow others' advice and map the two `TicketFlag` objects.

Comment: I understand why it needs a default ctor. In this case, it makes no sense to even try and call it (and I don't want a default ctor to provide for callers, they really need to be using the parameterized one). You're correct - I should be using the other's answers. Good explanation.