# Field reference and reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

One class has a field. Second class should be able to reference that field and to change it. Since you cannot get the address of a field in memory, I have to use reflections. But my approach only works on non-encapsulated fields. So basically:

This works:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public int field;
    public Dummy(int value)
    {
        this.field = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dummy d = new Dummy(20);
        //Shows 20
        Console.WriteLine(d.field.ToString());
        d.GetType().GetField("field", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(d, 40);
        //It should show 40 now
        Console.WriteLine(d.field.ToString());
    }
}
```

This doesn't (throws NullReferenceException):

```
public class Dummy
{
    public int field { get; set; }
    public Dummy(int value)
    {
        this.field = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dummy d = new Dummy(20);
        //Shows 20
        Console.WriteLine(d.field.ToString());
        d.GetType().GetField("field", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(d, 40);
        //It should show 40 now
        Console.WriteLine(d.field.ToString());
    }
}
```

Why? How do I fix it? Can I even access an encapsulated object like that? Thank you!

Comment: In your second example, that is not a `field`, its a `property`.

Comment: Why do you need reflection here? Both the `field` and the `property` are public, so `d.field = 40;`...

Comment: It's rather just a silly example to make things clear. You obviously don't need reflection here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a field any longer. Instead of GetField you should use GetProperty method:

```
d.GetType().GetProperty(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you could (and should) write

```
d.field = 40;
```

When you want a field to be non-private, you [should always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c) make it a property, as in your second example. You should never have public fields. Note that if you need to access a property via reflection, you'd use [`GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [`GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise about the use case?
Maybe an interface that isolates the properties' accessors is better:

```
public interface IDummy
{
    int field { get; set; }
}
```

You'll be able to manipulate the property without knowing anything about the rest of the object. Isn't that what you need when you want to "reference" a single field?

Comment: You are surely right but in my case there's too much variety to use interface. I just wanted a class that holds an object reference and when it gets changed - it changes the field / property elsewhere. That thing up there is just a silly example to make it clear to see where's the error.

Comment: Perfect. I guess you'll poll the value then. Needless to say that setters + events are excellent for these cases. I sense you don't have access to the source code and can't get around polling...