# Why use expression-bodied properties for primitive values?

Tags: c#, properties, expression-body, expression-bodied-members

What are the pros and cons of expression-bodied properties vs straight property declarations? For example, is there any advantage to using;

```
public string Foo => "Bar"
```

vs simply

```
public string Foo = "Bar"
```

My understanding was the `=>` is used when the value comes from a method, like a lambda function. If the value is a primitive like a string or int, why would anyone use an expression-bodied property for that?

Comment: They are different declarations

Comment: Duplicate of “why use properties”... searching for the link

Comment: This does seem less about expression-bodied properties and more about why use properties over fields: [Why use simple properties instead of fields in C#? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374416/why-use-simple-properties-instead-of-fields-in-c)  That is also a dup, but has some good anwsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few differences between those two lines of code:

1. The first one is a property, the second is a field. For example, you cannot `ref` the first `Foo`.
2. The property gets evaluated and returns a new object every time, even if the object is the same string literal. The variable is evaluated once and when used it's just loaded. (Note that a better way to write #1 is `public string Foo { get; } = "Bar";` which would also be initialized once and then return the same value).
3. The first one is read-only (it's a getter only), while the second one is a mutable variable, you can write into it. A closer equivalent would be `public readonly string Foo = "Bar";` or even better `public static readonly string Foo = "Bar";`

Comment: The second is a [_field_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not a variable.

Comment: Sure, field. Semantics :)