# Access a integer variable through a separate Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

Hey guys sorry if this is a re-post i checked for the answer through other sites as well as this but the information wasn't sufficient plus I'm still learning a lot.

But my question is that i have my engine class which is called `keepFocusEngine` and another class called `mcStar` i haven't ran across this problem so i don't really understand how to do it but i want to access a Integer variable from the `mcStar` through my `keepFocusEngine`. So in my  `mcStar` class i have a integer variable called `private var speed:Number;` which holds this in it `speed = 2 + Math.random()*2;`. I want to change the speed variable to this `speed = 10 + Math.random()*2;` from my `keepFocusEngine` through this function:

```
private function shootPlayerObject(e:TouchEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP)
        {
            btnShootPlayer = true;
        }else
        {
            btnShootPlayer = false;
        }
    }
```

so if the `btnShootPlayer = true;` i want the `speed = 10 + Math.random()*2;` to be called on.

Sorry if i confused anyone I'm kind of confusing myself haha. 
But do you understand what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: You named it `private`, this means you can't change it while it's private. It'll be better if you write a function for your ship that would be called at a specific event, which will in turn alter its speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it neatly, you can write getter/setter functions in your `keepFocusEngine` class. Then you can leave your `speed` variable to private. The getter and setter have to be public, ofcourse, to be reached outside the class.

In your `keepFocusEngine`, add the following:

```
public function GetSpeed() : Number
{
    return speed;
}

public function SetSpeed(newspeed:Number)
{
    speed = newspeed;
}
```

Then you can change your provided code into:

```
private function shootPlayerObject(e:TouchEvent):void 
{
    if (e.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP)
    {
        btnShootPlayer = true;
        keepFocusEngine.SetSpeed(10 + Math.random()*2);
    }else
    {
        btnShootPlayer = false;
    }
}
```

If at any point you'd like to know the speed, you can use `keepFocusEngine.GetSpeed()`. This makes it easier to program since you have some insight in your classpath. Also, when a getter or setter is called, you can do whatever  you want in that function. If it seems easier for you to always return the speed*10 for example, a getter can `return speed*10;`.

EDIT: I'd like to refer to this question: [Why prefer Properties to public variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables)

Comment: AS3 actually has support for true getters and setters. `public function set varName( value:DataType ):void {}` and `public function get varName():DataType {}`

Comment: Thank you Joetjah for the response ill try it out later today and let you know if it worked right!

Comment: @Apocalyptic what do you mean "true" getters and setters? How would your code above work?

Comment: @user2233653 You would access it just as you would a normal variable. So... `public function set varName( value:DataType ):void {}` and `public function get varName():DataType {}` in `ClassName`. You then declare a ClassName object and access varName like this: `var obj:ClassName = new ClassName(); obj.varName = "test"`. See [Step 13 in this Article](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-inheritance-setters-getters-basix/)

Comment: @JoetJah   I tried your method but i keep getting an error "possibly undefined method through a static type class. Also wouldn't i put the getter/setter inside the mcStar class? since thats where the the speed variable is? sorry i think i left that information out. Then i would add this inside the keepFocusEngine();    mcStar.SetSpeed(10 + Math.random()*2);

Comment: You are correct! I've read the facts wrong. The getter and setter are indeed in the class your variable is in. `private` makes sure only methods from the same class can reach that variable. If you create public getters and setters, you can access the private variable (through a method then).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables I'd like to refer to this question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information and links. Really appreciate it. Already read most of it. But im not sure what is going wrong here. I did all the steps and corrected the class issue but i still get this error: keepFocusEngine.as:574: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method SetSpeed through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: When you call `SetSpeed`, make sure you have the parameter in it. Also, make sure you have an instance of the object. So, for example, you run: `keepFocusEngine.getInstance().SetSpeed(10 + Math.random()*2);` How does that work out?