# What is the difference between a field and an auto property?

Tags: c#

I cannot see what the differences between these two classes are:

```
class Class1
{
    public int a;
}

class Class2
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

Why is the latter used when one can use the former?

Comment: Another similar question: [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a property, you can turn your "variable" into a getter/setter paradigm after the fact, and you'll break less code

properties also tend to play better with frameworks that make use of reflection

Comment: Although I agree with you and this is generally considered the real reason, IMO the first argument doesn't really makes sense. You could just as easily convert a field into a property.

Comment: @Kenneth  if you do that, than [programs that use your library will have to re-compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables%5C)

Comment: Also, a property can be declared in an interface, but a field can't.

Comment: You are right about that, I forgot about that one. However, in most situations, you either have control over the other apps (most I say) and even if you don't, if you make this change, you'll probably change other things as well, so a recompile will be necessary anyway. Anyway, I think we agree on the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int a { get; set; }
```

define a property :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69wcs43.aspx

Getters and Setters are implicits