# How to pass parameter to class C#?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I have code as below

```
public  class LocalDB
{
    public static int e_SessionID;

    public static string e_EventName;

    public static string e_TimeCreate;
}
```

in other class:

```
public static LocalDB newEvent ;
public void something()
    {
      newEvent.e_SessionID=123;
    }
```

but it is can not pass value.

Answer (score 7):

**Problem :** You are trying to access the static feilds using instance reference variable `newEvent` as below:

```
newEvent.e_SessionID=123;
//^^^Here
```

**Solution :** You need to use `classname` to access the `static` fields

```
newEvent.e_SessionID=123;
//^^^Replace with classname LocalDB here
```

Replace this:

```
 newEvent.e_SessionID = 123;
```

With this:

```
LocalDB.e_SessionID = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

Static methods and variables can only invoke using the class name 
and you are trying to call using the class object.

if you want to set the value of `e_SessionID` set the value using class name as follows

```
LocalDB.e_SessionID=123;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set them up as properties? Have a read of this SO post [why prefer properties to public variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables)

"Fields are considered implementation details of classes and exposing them publicly breaks encapsulation."

```
public class LocalDB
{
    public int SessionID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use property instead:

```
public  class LocalDB
{
   public int e_SessionID { get; set; }
   public string e_EventName { get; set; }
   public string e_TimeCreate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prefer instance data to static data.**

Static data is effectively global state. Do you have only one event in the lifetime of your program? What if you need to support multithreading? This is object-oriented programming; use objects.

**Encapsulate data.**

Avoid making fields public. Prefer properties, as others have stated. Note that this allows assigning the creation time at construction (and only then).

**Use appropriate types.**

If you are storing a date/time value, normally you would use the `DateTime` class.

**Favor immutability.**

If you know the values of properties at construction time, set them then and don't allow them to be changed.

**Think about names.**

Descriptive names matter, especially when you're doing maintenance after six months. I didn't change the name of `LocalDB` in my example, as I don't know your domain or use case. However, this class looks more like an event than a database to me. Would `Event` be a better name?

*The following example uses C# 6 syntax; earlier versions would need to add private setters and move the initialization to the constructor.*

```
public class LocalDB
{
    public LocalDB(int sessionID, string eventName)
    {
        SessionID = sessionID;
        EventName = eventName;
    }

    public int SessionID { get; }
    public string EventName { get; }
    public DateTime TimeCreate { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

public class Other
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        NewEvent = new LocalDB(1, "Other Event");
    }

    public LocalDB NewEvent { get; private set; }
}
```

A flaw in this example is that the `NewEvent` property of an `Other` instance will be `null` on creation. Avoid nulls where possible. Perhaps this should be a collection of events; not knowing your use case I can't say.