# Properties and Public variables

Tags: c#, oop

**I am having hard time understanding logic of properties , as far as i looked in internet its more logical and safe to use properties instead of public variables. But i want to understand the logic of properties to scratch it on my mind**

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
public int myVar;
```

**What are the benefits of using properties instead of public variables ? Why i shouldnt write a public variable in my class and use from instance?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables

Comment: In short, Property allows you restrict access to getter or setter with `private` modifier and execute some code inside it.

Comment: @aepot so inside set if i make this like if(myvar == 15) else if (myvar == 30) whenever i try to modify this myVar variable  it will execute all if and elses inside of it ?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? please explain a bit more

Comment: Yes, code will be executed as usual, and you may involve reserved word `value` in calculations for setter.

Comment: Based on what i pass to variable from another class, i want so that he would change somethings like integers ,strings without making a function for it , for an example if i pass 10 to myVar variable i want so that he would change to 15 himself without functions @curiousBoy

Comment: than you can use property and do that in your setter. BUT if you are executing code in a property, make sure you've written a property and not a method. A property should do less work-- a lot less work-- than a method. Properties should be lightweight. If your property incurs significant effort, it should be refactored into an explicit method.

Comment: Btw, this question is overduplicated on StackOverflow. Please use search to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, you want to execute a code before you are setting the value. So simple example would be:

```
  class Example
    {
        DayOfWeek _day;
        public DayOfWeek Day
        {
            // whenever you try to get this value, it will run this block
            get
            {
                // We don't allow this to be used on Friday.
                if (this._day == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid access");
                }
                return this._day;
            }
            // whenever you try to set its value, it will run this block
            set
            {
                // We dont allow to set if it is saturday
                if (value == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid access");
                } 
                this._day = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Getters and setters basically let you execute "lightweight" code before you access/set the value.

**BUT** if you are executing code in a property, make sure you've written a property and not a method. A property should do less work-- a lot less work-- than a method. Properties should be lightweight. If your property incurs significant effort, it should be refactored into an explicit method.
There are more to that.. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737290/why-prefer-properties-to-public-variables) as there are some helpful content.

Comment: That is what i wanted to learn overall, thank you so much (var olasın yurtdaş)