# Private List with Getter/Setter vs Public List

Tags: java, list, getter, access-modifiers

Would it be better to make a global List in a class private and have getter and setter methods or would it be better to just make it public? What is the standard in Java?

I was taught to make variables private, and just have getter and setter methods, but it definitely looks better accessing a public list than a private one.

```
public exampleclassThatContainsTheList.goodieList.add("Candy");

private exampleclassThatContainsTheList.setGoodieList(exampleclassThatContainsTheList.getGoodieList().add("Candy"));
```

That's my opinion, but of course I would prefer to go by standards than to go by what looks good.

Comment: It's good way to use private instance member along with public getter/setter to avoid unwanted modification in the state of the variable. Here setter method works as **security guard**. It provides single point of contact. Read more about [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: Why not have a method `add()` that takes the object `"Candy"` and adds it to the list? `classThatContainsTheList.add("Candy");` ?

Comment: Though not written in stone, the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) provides some good advice in these situations.

Comment: @AntonH If I did that, wouldn't I be required to add all the other methods related to a collection? Not required, but I might as well if I was going to use them.

Comment: This is called encapsulation. The benefits are numerous, but generally fall under the umbrella of abstraction. You can change what the `get` method does without breaking dependent classes. You cannot do this with direct member access.

Comment: @dalawh You add the methods that give the functionality you need. If you only need add and delete, just have methods that do these. The methods would act on the list in the classic way. I'm not saying it's the best way, but it is a possibility to consider.

Comment: @MarkPeters If I provide a getter and setter method to a private List, it would ultimately be the same?

Comment: @dalawh: The advantage of only implementing what the clients need is that you can change the underlying implementation details later.  For example, if you want to change it to be a `Set` rather than a `List`, you can do that.  But if you expose the list and clients start relying on, say, `getGoodieList().get(2)`, you can't do that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am aware of that, but I don't plan on adding additional functionally. Back to your statement; are you recommending I make it private?

Comment: @MarkPeters Understood.

Answer (score 2):

First at all, you should not use `public` fields directly unless they are constant (`static final`) fields and **making sure their state won't change**. They should be exposed using [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to avoid a client of your class modifying the state. Here's an example when writing your own framework by implementing getter/setter in defensive way, in order to not alter the current state of your `List`:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<String> stringList;
    public Foo() {
        //always initialized, never null
        this.stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public List<String> getStringList() {
        //defensive implementation
        //do not let clients to alter the state of the list
        //for example, avoiding clear the list through getStringList().clear()
        return new ArrayList(stringList);
    }
    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
        //defensive implementation
        //do not let clients to pass a null parameter
        this.stringList = (stringList == null) ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(stringList);
    }
}
```

Apart of this, the [JavaBean specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) states that fields in a Java class should not be `public` and their access should be through getter and setter methods.

> 7 Properties
>
> Properties are discrete, named attributes of a Java Bean that can affect its appearance or its behavior. For example, a GUI button might have a property named “Label” that represents the text displayed in the button.
>
> Properties show up in a number of ways:
>
> 1. Properties may be exposed in scripting environments as though they were fields of
>      objects. So in a Javascript environment I might do “b.Label = foo” to set the value of a
>      property.
> 2. Properties can be accessed programmatically by other components calling their getter
>      and setter methods (see Section 7.1 below).
>
> (...)
>
> 7.1 Accessor methods
>
> Properties are always accessed via method calls on their owning object. For readable properties there will be a *getter* method to read the property value. For writable properties there will be a *setter* method to allow the property value to be updated.

There are frameworks that follow these specifications in order to allow injection/retrieval of values for class fields through reflection. For example, Spring and JSF.

Spring example through XML configuration:

```xml
<bean id="fooBean" class="my.package.Foo">
    <property name="stringList">
        <list>
            <value>Hello</value>
            <value>World</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the associated Java class:

```
package my.package;

public class Foo {
    private List<String> stringList;
    public String getStringList() {
        return this.stringList;
    }
    //allows Spring to set the value of stringList through reflection
    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }
}
```

JSF example for field binding using [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el.htm):

```html
<!-- allows JSF to call getter through reflection -->
<h:dataTable value="#{foo.stringList}" var="value">
    <h:column>
        #{value}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And the associated Java class:

```
package my.package;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Foo {
    private List<String> stringList;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        stringList = new List<>();
        stringList.add("Hello");
        stringList.add("world");
    }
    public String getStringList() {
        return this.stringList;
    }
    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }
}
```

Which option to use: Defensive getter/setter or common getter/setter? It will depend on what you're doing.

Comment: This answer was really clear and the code sample illustrates and explains what needs to be done perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is to have private instance variables and public getter/setter methods (like you were taught). You always want to encapsulate or "hide" data, that is one of the fundamental concepts of OOP. One of the main benefits of this (among others) is to modify our implemented code without breaking the code of other developers who may be using the same code. This approach will also add maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I would go one step further:

Why should anyone know how you store your data? *Information hiding* is the keyword. In your example details about the datatype *leak* to the outside. The keyword *list* leaks details about the implementation, which is 1) unnecessary information - you could even name it *treasurechest* 2) does a possible user of your class make assumptions about the implementation, which is a bad thing. Give your class a *domain*-name like *goodies* and name the methods like *put* / *pull*. If you want to add multiple elements I would use a more generic Interface like *Iterable*.

Answer (score 0):

It be better to make a global List in a class private and have getter and setter methods

There are some advantages of using getter/setter

- getters and setter can have validation in them, fields can't
- using getter you can get subclass of wanted class.
- getters and setters are polymorphic, fields aren't
- debugging can be much simpler, because breakpoint can be placed
  inside one method not near many references of that given field.
- they can hide implementation changes

To know in more detail go through following links

[Advantage of set and get methods vs public variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071407/advantage-of-set-and-get-methods-vs-public-variable)

[Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

: