# Is it ok to get variable value directly instead of using getter in Java?

Tags: java, getter, convention

I'm writing program which operates on coordinate system so I need to use coordinates pretty often. I decided to use [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class because it obviously allows to easily store coordinates of a point.

The problem is everywhere in my program I store it as `int` whereas `Point` returns double when using `getX()` and `getY()` methods. Of course I can easily cast it to `int` but it doesn't look very elegant and adds unnecessary mess to the code.

Is it ok if I will just get the value directly? Like this:

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
int x = p.x;
```

instead of:

```
int x = p.getX();
```

I'm not even sure if it makes any difference, I just know that getters and setters are there for a reason and should be used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071407/advantage-of-set-and-get-methods-vs-public-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantage of set and get methods vs public variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071407/advantage-of-set-and-get-methods-vs-public-variable)

Comment: @MohamedAneesA I've seen this thread but it's about situation where I'm creating my own class. In my case class already exists and is not mine. I just want to know if it's bad practice to get the value directly.

Comment: I would suggest that if you wish to access the data in this way, you would be better served by creating your own class that contains `Point` and provides accessors delegating to the `Point`. In this way, you `Decorate` the class and leverage composition. If you then decide to store the data directly as `int` in the future, you would be protected.  Edit: davidxxx has an example of just using your own directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm writing program which operates on coordinate system so I need to
>   use coordinates pretty often. I decided to use Point class because it
>   obviously allows to easily store coordinates of a point.

and

> The problem is everywhere in my program I store it as int whereas
>   Point returns double when using getX() and getY() methods.

Are you sure that it obviously allows to easily store coordinates of a point for your domain?

I don't think.
Using the `java.awt.Point` classes makes sense if you need to manipulate some  `java.awt.Point` instances.

The class doesn't seem suit to your need.

- If you really don't need to use `java.awt.Point` :

You should create and use your own `Point` class that returns `int` value when you write :

```
int x = p.getX();
```

- If you change your mind and you happen to need to use `java.awt.Point` for some tasks:

In the custom `Point` class, add a method to return a `java.awt.Point` instance.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I don't really know why but I thought it's much better to use existing class than create a very similar one.

Comment: You are welcome :) Interesting question. You are right : it's much better to use existing class than creating very similar one ... **but only if it addresses your need**. This class is rather old and is not very easy to use. It inherits from `Point2D` that manipulates `double`. It is not really a concern if `Point` had also specific methods : `getIntX()` and a `getIntY()`. But it has not them. So, using `Point` makes sense only when you **are compelled to** or **you can take advantage of it** (for example to send a Point  object to an existing or a third party class that do a task for you).

Answer (score 1):

@Sarjan Yes...some might argue that setters and getters are evil. But I guess it perfectly helps in various situations particularly in large projects. A sample example is validation. Say,if you want to set x only if it is greater than 0, you cannot perform it elegantly if it is public(unless you have a check before setting the variable..everywhere!!!...Tedious right?? And missing it will crash your system someday if some new programmer works on your project and unaware of this)..if you use a setter, you can check if it is greater than 0 inside the setter itself and thus provides easy implementation!!

PS: I couldn't comment this since it is too long and hence written as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have linked documentation about `Point`. So read carefully and think of your problem rather that starting to code and thinking, **First think of an idea**. Then get to know that the `java.awt.point` class is best fit to your situation or not.

If it is not fit to your situation you can implement a class. Otherwise, follow documentation. It is a good practice to follow documentation and also OOP concept.

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
```

If you have followed the documentation, you will see like this:

> `Point()`:
>   Constructs and initializes a point at the origin (0, 0) of the
>   coordinate space.

I think you donot have clear idea about this. However,

```
Point p = new Point();
int x = p.x;
```

This is not a problem because `x` is `public` and its your program. But why they have implemented this:

```
getX();
```

Also read these- [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters), [implementation of Point class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Point.java).

Answer (score 0):

Let, You have 2 classes. These are: `Class A` & `Class B`

In Class A, you have an private instance variable.

**Class A:**

```
Class A {
    private int a;

    public int getA() {
        return A;
    }

}
```

Now you want to access variable named `a` of `Class A` from `Class B`. But the variable is private. So, now we need the getter method as the getter method is public.

**Class B:**

```
Class B {
    public void fetchA() {
        A classA = new A();
        int a = classA.getA();
    }
}
```

In this case, we need getter methods.