# (Duplicated) Difference between 'public int x;' and 'public int x { get; set; }

Tags: c#, properties, duplicates

**What is the difference, if any, between**

```
public int x;
```

**and**

```
public int x { get; set; }
```

**?**

Comment: the first one is a public variable while the second is a public property.

Comment: if there was just a site where you could search such things like 
i dont know, Google? https://www.google.co.il/search?q=difference+between+properties+and+variables+c%23&oq=difference+between+properties+and+variabl&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.11837j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=properties+vs+variables+c%23

Comment: In this case he didn't have anything to google.  He didn't know it was a "property".  Therefore what exactly could he have put in a google search?  I think it's a fair question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

Comment: @TomerW: yep didn't find this because I didn't have the correct key terms :/ But thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-implemented getters and setters vs. public fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111461/auto-implemented-getters-and-setters-vs-public-fields)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is called a field.  The second one is a property, in this case an **auto-implemented property**.

Properties act like fields but use a getter and a setter function to retrive and set the value.  Another way of writing the above property is as follows:

```
private int _x;
public int X
{
    get
    {
        return _x;
    }
    set
    {
        _x = value;
    }
}
```

The variable `_x` in this case is called a *backing field*.  With an auto-implemented property you can't access the backing field or customize code in the getter/setter, but if you don't need to than it's shorter and more succinct.

As a rule in C# most of the time any public member should be exposed as a property instead of a field.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is public variable which can be accessed from anywhere.

The second one is public property

Check Properties [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w86s7x04.aspx) for details.

> Properties have many uses: they can validate data before allowing a
>   change; they can transparently expose data on a class where that data
>   is actually retrieved from some other source, such as a database; they
>   can take an action when data is changed, such as raising an event, or
>   changing the value of other fields.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between thise two is that a property can do something *more* than just get / set a variable. 
take this example:

```
private int _x;
public int x 
{ 
    get 
    {
      //do something
      return _x;
    } 
    set
    {
      if(_x != value)
      PropertyChanged("x");
      _X = value;
    }
}
```

when we set the property - we notify something ( `PropertyChanged()`) that the value has changed. It would be very hard to do with just the field

Comment: Yes, but given the exact code, without any added functionality like events or value checks, is there any practical difference at all? In other words, why type { get set } after a public property if all you ever do is set and get the value of X directly?

Comment: I never type 'get; set;'  :-) i type 'prop' and press Tab. And them i am ready if, later, i need to add functionallity.